# HTML - Bootstrap: Sidebar pushes main content down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I have this web page:
[image: move content up]

as it shows in the image, I want the main text to come right after the heading, but the sidebar pushes it down. How can I fix this problem?

The code is:

```
<div class="row content-area-main">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="img/double-lily-modified3.png" alt="LilyPond logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 header-info">
              <h1 class="header-info-title">LilyPond</h1>
                <p>... music notation for everyone</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="card card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Stable Release</h4>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Download 2.18.2</a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Manuals 2.18.2</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="card card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Unstable Release</h4>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Download 2.19.51</a></li>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Manuals 2.19.51</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="card card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Pondings</h4>
                  <p>The LilyPond Blog is up and running <a href="http://www.lilypondblog.org/" target="_blank">here</a>! Anyone can follow and leave comments on the blog. To contribute, contact <a href="mailto:ul@openlilylib.org">Urs Liska</a>.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-area-main">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <p>LilyPond is a music engraving program, devoted to producing the highest-quality sheet music possible. It brings the aesthetics of traditionally engraved music to computer printouts. LilyPond is free software and part of the GNU Project.</p>
              <p class="header-info-link">Read more in our <a href="#">Introduction</a>!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-area">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Beatuiful Sheet Music</h4>
                  <img src="img/bwv861-lilypond.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail card-image-custom" width="100%">
                  <p class="card-text">LilyPond is a powerful and flexible tool for engraving tasks of all kinds, for example classical music (like the example above by J.S. Bach), complex notation, early music, modern music, tablature, vocal music, lead sheets, educational materials, large orchestral projects, customized output, and even Schenker graphs.</p>
                  <span class="card-link">Browse our gallery of <a href="#">Examples</a> and be inspired!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row content-area-main">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="img/double-lily-modified3.png" alt="LilyPond logo">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 header-info">
                <h1 class="header-info-title">LilyPond</h1>
                <p>... music notation for everyone</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-area-main">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p>LilyPond is a music engraving program, devoted to producing the highest-quality sheet music possible. It brings the aesthetics of traditionally engraved music to computer printouts. LilyPond is free software and part of the GNU Project.</p>
              <p class="header-info-link">Read more in our <a href="#">Introduction</a>!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row content-area">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card card-block">
                  <h4 class="card-title">Beatuiful Sheet Music</h4>
                  <img src="img/bwv861-lilypond.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail card-image-custom" width="100%">
                  <p class="card-text">LilyPond is a powerful and flexible tool for engraving tasks of all kinds, for example classical music (like the example above by J.S. Bach), complex notation, early music, modern music, tablature, vocal music, lead sheets, educational materials, large orchestral projects, customized output, and even Schenker graphs.</p>
                  <span class="card-link">Browse our gallery of <a href="#">Examples</a> and be inspired!</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Stable Release</h4>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Download 2.18.2</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Manuals 2.18.2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Unstable Release</h4>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Download 2.19.51</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#" target="_blank">Manuals 2.19.51</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">Pondings</h4>
            <p>The LilyPond Blog is up and running <a href="http://www.lilypondblog.org/" target="_blank">here</a>! Anyone can follow and leave comments on the blog. To contribute, contact <a href="mailto:ul@openlilylib.org">Urs Liska</a>.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Grid systems are used for creating page layouts through a series of
>   rows and columns that house your content. Use rows to create
>   horizontal groups of columns.

**[Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**

Your `.row` clears the last `.row`. Try placing your content in the column you'd like it within the same `.row`.

Comment: how do I space it to the left then? Can you add a snippet?

Comment: Also, the problem is that the image is in the first row, but it if I put the other text in that row as well, it gets scaled into that row. I want it to be exactly formatted as it is now.